# How to change `this` context calling Vue instance methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, bind

`.call`, `.apply`, `.bind` methods of `Function.prototype` don't work for functions once defined as methods of Vue instance in `.vue` file.

I'm using `@vue/cli` project, compiled with `vue-cli-service serve`.
Here's reduced example of code, which can be placed in any Vue single-file component definition.

```
    methods: {
        foo() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.foo.call({ bar: 42 });
        this.foo.apply({ bar: 42 });
        this.foo.bind({ bar: 42 })();
    }
```

Expected output to the console is triple `{ bar: 42 }`, since `this` value was changed for these calls.
However, `VueComponent` object is printed to the console.

I checked these methods for overloading, using 
`this.foo.bind === Function.prototype.bind // returns true`,
they are not overloaded.

It may be caused by Vue using `Proxy` objects or even by templates compilation.

Simplest `@vue/cli` project with code above will be enough to reproduce the problem.

Thanks

Comment: `this.foo({bar:42})` is sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue component methods are bound to the context, which is component instance. This could be checked with:

```
function foo() {
    foo() {
        console.log(this);
    }

}

...
methods: { foo },
created() {
    this.foo !== foo // true
}
...
```

`this.foo.bind === Function.prototype.bind` check isn't representative since `this.foo` is regular function, so it inherits `bind`.

Once a function is bound, it cannot be re-bound or be called with different context:

```
const context = {};
const boundFoo = (function foo() { return this; }).bind(context);
// boundFoo.call({}) === context
// boundFoo.bind({})() === context
```

It isn't a good practice to rely on arbitrary dynamic `this` context in JS OOP. If a method needs a context, it should be provided to it as an argument:

```
methods: {
    foo(ctx) {
        console.log(ctx);
    }
},
created() {
    this.foo({ bar: 42 });
}
```

Or be shared as instance property, depending on the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer.
It's very odd, that `bind` function makes it impossible to ever call the resulted function with different context. Looks pretty shortsighted for me. Do you know for any reason it's designed this way?

Comment: I can't agree about not being a good practice to rely on `this` context in JS. It's not really a good practice to write in JS, from that point (and I would agree with that).
But yet, prior to this particular problem, I found no reasons not to use bizarre, odd and unpredictable `this` keyword in JS. Also, Vue forces programmers to use `this` context by design.

Comment: This allows to pass methods as callbacks without losing original context, `<component :callback-prop="foo" />`, something that would require to `bind` them explicitly in `created` otherwise. A workaround would be to use `data` to define `foo`, it isn't bound automatically. The statement referred to *arbitrary dynamic* `this`, not just any `this`. The former was overused in jQuery and other legacy libs instead of params, one of reasons it declined is that it doesn't work with arrows.

Comment: See how `bind` works here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill . It does `fn.apply(myContext)` internally and ignores `this` that was provided to it when you're trying to `call` or re-bind bound function.